# How to convert python script to pascal script?

Tags: python, inno-setup, pascal

I have app that need [Inno Setup](https://jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) to pack it. And aslo i need to write some Pascal code in `[Code]` section.The problem is that i am very familiar with python but not familiar with Pascal,So i want to know it's there have any tool covert python code to pascal code, or some other methods, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you won't be able to directly convert python code to pascal
Python is a dynamically typed interpreted language, whereas Pascal is a statically typed compiled language. This means that any converter would need to know the type of every variable used in your python script, which can change throughout a script.

Providing you know the typings of your python code your easiest solution if the Pascal is 100% required would be to go through your python line by line and re-write in Pascal using online resources to find the equivalant syntaxes.
Some things won't convert cleanly due to changing of types mid script, these will need to be corrected.

Comment: I think my dream had break down, maybe i should write simple pascal code in `inno setup` `[Code]` section, pascal language i had never know it before.